# What does the `%` character do in GNU Make?

Tags: gnu-make

I am using GNU make. In a Makefile that I got, i see the symbol '%'. e.g. in context of 
%.c, %.asm , %.o etc.. (Is it a wildcard that will return all the files of that extension)

What does % mean?

What will the below rule do:

```
%.o:  %.c
  gcc $< -o:$@
```

thank you,

-AD

Comment: This question is "what aim are wildcards for?"  There was another question phrased "how can I achieve the aim" with answer "with wildcards!"  I'd call it a reverse-dupe :-)  Here's the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1633527/wildcard-targets-in-a-makefile

Comment: I was reading about pattern rules at: gnu.org/software/automake/manual/make/Pattern-Rules.html There I read a statement which said: "A pattern rule looks like an ordinary rule, except that its target contains the character ‘%’ (exactly one of them). " What does exactly one of them mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule:

```
%.o:  %.c
    gcc $< -o:$@
```

Will for each c file build an object file using the command below it. So yes, % is like a wildcard, but I tend to think of it as "for each" because that's what happens as a result of the rule. `$<` means dependent files and `$@` means the object to be built. If you did this:

```
fred.o: fred.c
    gcc $< -o:$@
```

Here `$@=fred.o` and `$<=fred.c` Likewise

```
fred.o: fred.c george.c
    gcc $< -o:$@
```

gives `$@=fred.o` and `$<=fred.c george.c`.

Edit: from the commands I shall expand on this.

`%` will match everything matching that around it. So `%.c` means all the .c files in the current directory. `asm/%.asm` means all the files in the subdir asm with the `.asm` extension. It acts like a token, so whatever is found will be used whenever you next use `%` i.e. in the label.

So, the rule:

```
objs/asm/%.o: arch/%.S
     nasm -felf64 $< -o $@
```

Given `arch/hello.S`, `arch/bye.S`, `arch/somethingelse.S` will create `obj/asm/hello.o`, `obj/asm/bye.S`, `obj/asm/somethingelse.o`.

Comment: I was reading about pattern rules at: http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/make/Pattern-Rules.html      There I read a statement which said: "A pattern rule looks like an ordinary rule, except that its target contains the character ‘%’ (exactly one of them). " What does exactly one of them mean?. Also I had a pattern rule like: %.obj:  isp/%.asm   $(ASM)  $< -o:$@ but somehow it was not picking all the asm files for assembling. I added one assembly file later to that folder and it was not getting assembled. Had to manually add the build rule for that file.

Comment: It means that whatever % represents will be used everywhere % is mentioned. You can't match two things at once. That rule will match everything in isp/somename.asm and create somename.o. Try ls isp/*.asm. That's what isp/%.asm will match. Then it will take the %, put a .o on the end and that becomes the name of the rule (the thing to be made).

Comment: Ok , so if %.asm means for each asm file, convert each of those to *.obj. So when I add one more asm file to the existing files in the folder, but it was not getting assembled? What could be the reason. Sorry i am bit confused?