# Running Makefile targets

Tags: makefile

I am trying to 'fire' off the compilation by making all dependencies in a list of items, which are themselves targets.

From the answer (last, posted by Carl..)  given in seems to suggest that something like this is possible.

[Wildcard targets in a Makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1633527/wildcard-targets-in-a-makefile)

---

```
all:    $(OBJECTS)

OBJECTS = foo.o bar.o

bar.o:  bar.c
        @echo make $@

foo.o:  foo.c
        @echo make $@

.PHONY: all
```

My question is, when I run make I get the following, I cannot seem to get it to compile.

```
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
```

Comment: Posted in a rush! Updated the question.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "fire off the compilation"?

Comment: Do the `.o` files already exist?

Comment: no, this is a completely new folder, the only files that exist are foo.c bar.c and Makefile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reverse the order of the first two lines, like so:

```
OBJECTS = foo.o bar.o

all:    $(OBJECTS)
```

In your example, when Make gets to the `all` rule, `OBJECTS` has not yet been defined, so it resolves to this:

```
all:
```

Make sees a rule with no commands and no prerequisites-- nothing to be done.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```
 %.o: %.c
      $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

This means:

To make a `.o` file, we need a `.c` file with the same name ( represented by `%`). The command to make the `.o` file is the name of the C compiler `$(CC)`, followed by any compiler flags `$(CFLAGS)`, then `-c`, etc. `$<` is the name of the first prerequisite (`$^` is the names of all prerequisites, if you want that), and `$@` is the name of the target.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, replacing that will make it cleaner sure, however when I run make I still get a "make: Nothing to be done for `all'."