# For loop through names in GNU make

Tags: for-loop, makefile

I have a bunch of .dot files (for example, `a.dot, b.dot, c.dot`) and I want to compile them to .png files with `neato`. Currently, the make command I have to do that looks something like this:

```
neato -Tpng -o a.png a.dot
neato -Tpng -o b.png b.dot
neato -Tpng -o c.png c.dot
```

Obviously, this is completely non-scalable, and I'd like to write something that will take every file with a .dot extension, and compile it to an equivalently-named .png file. I'm not sure how to write such a loop in make - any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which 'make'? This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1633527/wildcard-targets-in-a-makefile

Comment: Edited to tell you which make I mean.

Comment: can we use `$<` and `$@`?

Comment: You don't need a loop, you need a rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty much basic make 101:

```
SRCS = a.dot b.dot c.dot

OBJS = $(SRCS:%.dot=%.png)

all: $(OBJS)

%.png : %.dot
        neato -Tpng -o $@ $<
```

You don't do "loops" in make; you define targets and prerequisites.