# Can a mex s-function component be recompiled only if it changed?

Tags: matlab, mex, nmake, s-function

In the first phase of testing my code has to run in a Matlab Simulink environment (2010b 32bits) compiled as S-function. The compiler is the one that comes with Visual Studio 2010.

I currently have a script that compiles my code that looks like this:

```
mex -c -v foo_main.c
mex -c -v foo_1.c
mex -c -v foo_2.c
% etc...


mex -v foo_wrapper.c foo_main.obj foo_1.obj foo_2.obj % etc...
```

During the years the number of files has greatly increased, to the extent that compilation takes quite some time.

My question is: does it exists a method to check if an `*.obj` does not correspond to its `*.c` counterpart and recompile it only when necessary?

I am wary of creating special scripts because I would have to change them on a case-by-case basis and I see this as a road prone to errors and unnecessary risks.

---

**EDIT:**

My current solution is to take the `date` property of the files and compare them:

```
c_file = dir(fullfile(pwd,'\\foo.c'));
obj_file = dir(fullfile(pwd,'\\foo.obj'));

if (datenum(c_file.date) > datenum(obj_file.date))
    mex -c -v foo.c
end
```

I understand that this is not the cleanest solution and, [in the comments, m.s.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30327130/can-a-mex-s-function-component-be-recompiled-only-if-it-changed?noredirect=1#comment48750066_30327130) suggests to use a `nmake` file. I never created one and I do not know how to use it from a Matlab script.

Can it be done? Which steps should I follow to create and use it?

Comment: how about using a [makefile with patterns](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1633553/678093)?

Comment: @m.s. should do fine, as I already use a special `mexopts.bat` (I understand that you are proposing to change this file, correct?).

Comment: Well, I propose to use GNU make or similiar which can be used to automatically determine if a certain obj file is "outdated" and needs to be recompiled.

Comment: @m.s. that I am not sure I can do, I have to compile through VS2010.

Comment: looks like Microsoft `nmake` can do similiar things: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/5006-makefile-for-mex#comment_10280

Comment: @m.s. that looks promising! any chances you could write a full answer?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know `nmake`, you might want to update your question, add the `nmake` tag and hope for someone with specific knowledge to answer your question.